# Wordpress register_setting sanitize_callback runs twice on initial save

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am trying out my skills on a Wordpress plugin.

I have a function to register the setting from a setting page and the sanitize_callback function gets called twice on the initial first save only.

The field in question needs to be encrypted because it's a password. So I thought of using this sanitize_callback call function to do it.

Maybe the wrong approach! How would you do it?

```php
$pswd_args = array(
            "type" => "string",
            "description" => "",
            "sanitize_callback" => array( $this, "encryptPSWD"),
            "show_in_rest" => false,
            "zzz_password"
        );
register_setting( self::OPTION_GROUPE_NAME, "zzz_password", $pswd_args );
```

I have search for some solution, but so far none.
I fould this post about what seams to be a bug report thats been running for quite some time, but not sure if this is 100% related to my issue.

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21989

Any work around would help!
Thanks

Comment: can you try: `'sanitize_callback' => 'encryptPSWD',`

Comment: No. It's in a class! This is the way to call a function within a WP function that is in a class... Unless there is another way that I don't know.

Comment: What hook is triggering your function?

Comment: @HowardE The calling hook is in my constructor ```add_action( "admin_init", array( $this, "registerSomeNameSettings" ));``` registerSomeNameSettings being the function that registers the setting shown in the question. This is a single instance of the class and no other one needed.

Comment: Same here, I am pretty sure it is a bug. It is called first time on the input (POST data), second time on the sanitized values and defaults where there is no value set. It happens only when the option is not saved yet in the database. I am going to report it.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a boolean property on your class and set it as false initially and on the `sanitize_callback` you can check: if it is false you can run the password encryption, if it is true you can skip the encryption, before returning the value you set the property to true.

```
class MyPlugin {
  
  protected bool $settingsRegistered = false;
  
  public function __construct() {
    add_action( 'admin_init', [ $this, 'registerSettings' ] );
  }
  
  public function registerSettings() {
    $pswd_args = array(
        "type" => "string",
        "description" => "",
        "sanitize_callback" => array( $this, "encryptPSWD"),
        "show_in_rest" => false,
        "zzz_password"
    );
    register_setting( self::OPTION_GROUPE_NAME, "zzz_password", $pswd_args );
  }

  public function encryptPSWD($settings) {
    if(!$this->settingsRegistered) {
      // Encrypt your password here
    }
    
    $this->settingsRegistered = true;
    return $settings;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to go around the issue.
I did some tests and what is in the [core.track](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21989) link seams to be what is happening.
The process on which the option goes through are:

1. Updating but nothing exist yet and use the sanitize_callback prior trying
2. Adding because the first try returned false and again sanitize_callback applied

So to go around it

1. I removed the sanitize_callback in the register_setting
2. added a filter using the pre_update_option_{ $option_name } hook

```php
$pswd_args = array(
            "type" => "string",
            "description" => "",
            "show_in_rest" => false,
            "zzz_password"
        );
register_setting( self::OPTION_GROUPE_NAME, "zzz_password", $pswd_args );
```

In the construtor

```php
 add_filter( "pre_update_option_my_option", array( $this, "function_name" ), 10, 2 );
```

This call takes care of modifying the value before adding or updating the value of the option being saved.
Strangely this hook does the same process as before but does not applied the callback function on the individual steps of the process.

Any improvement on this issue is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the exact same problem. Solved it by adding the not existing yet option before attempting to register it. When I tried to do this in the sanitize callback function I got back a 500 server error, so avoid that.

```
// check if the "fields_associations" option exists
$fields_associations = get_option( "fields_associations" );

// if the "fields_associations" option doesn't exist yet, add it with a default value
if ( $fields_associations === false ) {
    add_option( "fields_associations", '' );
}

// register a new setting with a sanitize/validation callback
register_setting( "plugin_general_settings", "fields_associations", "fields_associations_validation" );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a Wordpress bug. <strike>I reported it: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/60595#ticket</strike> Looks like it is a duplicate of the ticket you mentioned: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21989

As of a workaround since the second time it is called with already sanitized input I would wrap it this way until it is fixed:

```
function wrapSanitizer($sanitizer){
    $firstCall = true;
    return function ($input) use (&$firstCall, $sanitizer){
        if (!$firstCall)
            return $input;
        $firstCall = false;
        return call_user_func($sanitizer, $input);
    };
}

$pswd_args = array(
    // ...
    "sanitize_callback" => $this->wrapSanitizer(array( $this, "encryptPSWD")),
    // ...
);
```